# Multi data select SAPUI5 viz

Tags: javascript, sapui5

The following code gives me a nice line chart as shown below:

```
//Code snippet to create dataset  
var oDataset1 = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({  
  dimensions : [{axis : 1,name :'BUSINESS_DATE', value :"BUSINESS_DATE"}]  
  measures : [{name : 'Profit', value : '{Profit}'}], //Define the Y-axis parameter  
  data : {path : "/GRAPHDATA",filters: [oFilter1,oFilter2,oFilter3],parameters: {select: 'BUSINESS_DATE,PROFIT'}} //set the data and filter  
});
```

Define line chart:

```
var oLineChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Line({
  width : "100%",
  height : "300px",  
  //plotArea : {'colorPalette' :['#748CB2','#FFC200']},  
  title : {visible : true,text : 'BusinessDate Vs Profit'},  
  dataset : oDataset1,  
  selectData : function(oEvent) {  
    alert("Need to extend code");                     
  },  
});
```

[image]

Now, when I click on a single data point I need to get the values of X-axis and Y-axis of that data point selected. Could anyone suggest how this could be done? Any example solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [API documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.Line.html) you probably need the [`attachSelectData` function](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.Line.html#attachSelectData) which listens to selections of data.

Comment: This gives me only the Y axis value. But I need both X axis and Y axis value at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Get your Line Chart via Id

```
var line = sap.ui.getCore().byId("LineChart");
```

Get the model from the line chart

```
var json = line.getModel().getProperty("/GRAPHDATA");
```

now you can access the element clicked via row and column ID in the json and you got your X-Axis value...

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following code:

```
var oSelectData = oEvent.getParameter("GRAPHDATA");
var oContext = this.getDataset().findContext(oSelectData[0].data[0].ctx.path);
```

oContext will get the datapath followed by the data index.